# jquery for checking input value doesn't work

Tags: jquery, focus

I made a jquery "checkcus(str)" to check if the input field is empty. If I focus on the input field and it's empty, the background color of the input should become RED. Else, it should focus on the next input field with the id "nextInput".

```
function checkcus(str) {

   var i = document.getElementById(str).value;
   if( i === 'null' ) {
          document.getElementById(str).style.backgroundColor="red";

   }
   else {
         $('#nextInput').focus();


         }

   }
```

Here's my code for the input fields

Also, I don't need to put and check for the maxlength because the input is 'name' so there's should be no limit of characters.

```
<div id='input1'>
 Name <input type = 'text' id = 'firstInput' onfocus='checkcus(this.id)'>
  </div>
<div id = 'input2'>
 Code <input type = 'text' id = 'nextInput'>
</div>
```

I'm new to jquery and I think there's a problem in my code why it's not working.

Comment: Side note, if you're using jQuery, then *use* jQuery. E.g. instead of `document.getElementById(str).style.backgroundColor="red";` do `$('#'+str).css('backgroundColor','red')`

Answer (score 0):

If an input element is empty, then the value of the field will be an empty string(`''`), you are checking if it is a string value `'null'` which is not the same as the `null` value also.

```
function checkcus(str) {
    var el = document.getElementById(str);
    if (el.value === '') {
        el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('nextInput').focus();
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vswysgc5/)

---

Since you are using jQuery, use jQuery event handlers

```
Name<input type='text' id='firstInput'/>
Code<input type='text' id='nextInput'>
```

then

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#firstInput').focus(function(){
        if(this.value===''){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }else{
            $('#nextInput').focus();
        }
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vswysgc5/2/)

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I have another problem. I put the two <input> in different <div> tags and it's not working. Why is that? like this : <div id = 'input1'>Name <input type = 'text' id = 'firstInput' onfocus='checkcus(this.id)'></div>
<div='input2'>Code <input type = 'text' id = 'nextInput'> </div>

Comment: @makarov can you edit the above fiddles to recreate the problem

Comment: The problem could be that you have duplicate ids, ID of an element must be unique...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I know what's the problem now. You're right, I have two the same ID that' why its not working to me. Thanks @Arun

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the length of the input instead. I also jQuery-fied your example since you tagged your question with jQuery:

```js
$('#firstInput').focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length ===0) {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor','red');
    } else {
        $('#nextInput').focus();
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name
<input type='text' id='firstInput'>Code
<input type='text' id='nextInput'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give **jQuery** a shot ...

```js
$(function() {
    $('#firstInput').on('focusin', function() {
       if( this.value.trim() === '' ) {
           $(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
       } else {
           $('#nextInput').focus();
       }
    })
    .on('input',function() {
        if( this.value.trim() !== '' ) {
            $(this).css('background-color','#ffffff');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name <input type="text" id="firstInput" name="firstInput">
Code <input type="text" id="nextInput" name="nextInput">
```